# Backing up Mac OSX to Windows/Samba share

Tags: macos, mac, backup, samba, time-machine

This should not be this hard ... is there an easy way to back up a mac to a windows share?

so far, I've tried the suggestions here, but am getting error:
http://hupio.wordpress.com/2008/04/27/osx-timemachine-and-sambawindows-share/

Surely this isn't the only way. I'm currently trying to use time machine, but really I'd appreciate any other (free) backup solutions that you can suggest.

Comment: That's blog is really old. They updated the time machine detection routine sometime around 10.6. You may need to add "10.6" to your search terms and you should be able to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's unsafe, and not recommended.  Apple claims that a non-AFP (Apple File Protocol) server, may not flush the cache properly, and may lead to corruption of the Time Machine Backup.

Also, Windows shares do not support Hard Linking, in the manner that Apple requires for a Time Machine archive.  (Or at least, that is what Apple claims...)

A Unix file share may work...  But I do not believe you will be successful with a Windows share...

Comment: That's frustrating